# I need some help accurately trimming video using the FFmpeg C api

Tags: c, video, ffmpeg

I need some help accurately trimming video using the FFmpeg C api.
What I’m seeing is when the input video stream has a time_base of 1/48000 it correctly selects the trimmed start and end times. However when the input video stream has a time_base other than 1/48000 the trim is incorrect.

Time bases of 1/30000 and 1/24000 trim half the expected video stream length - 10s instead of 20s.
1/25 trims almost nothing at all - the output file size is only a few kb.

The audio stream appears to always be trimmed correctly.

For example if I try to trim the first 20s of a video whose video stream time base is 1/30000, the output mp4’s length is 20s. It has first 10s of video and first 20s of audio.

I *think* I'm incorrectly calculating the end_time but I'm not sure why it's correct for 1/48000 time_base streams.

```
record[i].start_time = av_rescale_q((int64_t)( start_time * AV_TIME_BASE ), default_timebase, in_stream->time_base);
record[i].end_time = av_rescale_q((int64_t)( end_time   * AV_TIME_BASE ), default_timebase, in_stream->time_base);
```

Here is a more complete sample of code:

```
int num_of_streams = ifmt_ctx->nb_streams;
if(num_of_streams > 0) {
    // keeps track of each stream's trimmed start and end times
    struct stream_pts record[num_of_streams];

    for (i = 0; i < num_of_streams; i++) {
        AVStream *in_stream = ifmt_ctx->streams[i];
        AVStream *out_stream = avformat_new_stream(ofmt_ctx, in_stream->codec->codec);
        if (!out_stream) {
            LOGE("=> Failed allocating output stream");
            ret = AVERROR_UNKNOWN;
            return close_connection(ret);
        }

        ret = avcodec_copy_context(out_stream->codec, in_stream->codec);
        if (ret < 0) {
            LOGE("=> Failed to copy context from input to output stream codec context");
            return close_connection(ret);
        }
        out_stream->codec->codec_tag = 0;
        if (ofmt_ctx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_GLOBALHEADER)
            out_stream->codec->flags |= CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;

        AVRational default_timebase;
        default_timebase.num = 1;
        default_timebase.den = AV_TIME_BASE;

        // determine start/end times for each stream
        record[i].index = i;
        record[i].start_time = av_rescale_q((int64_t)( start_time * AV_TIME_BASE ), default_timebase, in_stream->time_base);
        record[i].end_time = av_rescale_q((int64_t)( end_time   * AV_TIME_BASE ), default_timebase, in_stream->time_base);
    }

    av_dump_format(ofmt_ctx, 0, output_file, 1);

    if (!(ofmt->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        ret = avio_open(&ofmt_ctx->pb, output_file, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
        if (ret < 0) {
            LOGE("=> Could not open output file '%s'", output_file);
            return close_connection(ret);
        }
    }

    ret = avformat_write_header(ofmt_ctx, NULL);
    if (ret < 0) {
        LOGE("=> Error occurred when opening output file");
        return close_connection(ret);
    }

    while (1) {
        AVStream *in_stream, *out_stream;

        ret = av_read_frame(ifmt_ctx, &pkt);
        if (ret < 0)
            break;

        in_stream  = ifmt_ctx->streams[pkt.stream_index];
        out_stream = ofmt_ctx->streams[pkt.stream_index];

        // copy packet
        pkt.pts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt.pts, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base, AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF|AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX);
        pkt.dts = av_rescale_q_rnd(pkt.dts, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base, AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF|AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX);
        pkt.duration = av_rescale_q(pkt.duration, in_stream->time_base, out_stream->time_base);
        pkt.pos = -1;

        // write the frames we're looking for
        if(pkt.pts >= record[pkt.stream_index].start_time && pkt.pts <= record[pkt.stream_index].end_time) {
            ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(ofmt_ctx, &pkt);
            if (ret < 0) {
                LOGE("=> Error muxing packet");
                break;
            }
        }

        av_free_packet(&pkt);
    }
}
```